# how to auto fill a column of file/folder based on parent folder's value of that column in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: folder

Is there a way to create a workflow to auto fill a column value based on parent folder's same column value.

I have the parent folder "Contracts". I assigned a category column for it called "Contracts".

Inside the parent folder, there are 10 other folders, and 100+ different files. I want all of them to inherit the parent folder's category automatically.

Is there workflow I can run for this?

This is for Sharepoin 2013 enterprise version. Please keep in mind that we are not setup with powershell and I have absolutely no experience in coding.

Comment: Library Settings -> Column default value settings?

Comment: That would set the column value for the whole library. I just want to automate column value for a folder and its contents inside the library.

Comment: You can dive into specific folders and set values for files added to that folder

Answer (score 1):

**Have you tried a Document Set folder?**

Each Document Set can apply the column value to all items inside it. See screenshot.

[image]

Comment: No I have not tried Document Set as of yet. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: Let me know if this works. NOTE: if you move a file from one document set to another, it will take a few minutes for the Category column to update.