# Make a column auto update by Parent Folder Value

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, column, flow, default-value, microsoft-flow

I am setting up a new Document Library to organize several different types of Documents.  I have a Folder View and a Metadata view.  I am using a column named "Section" to sort the metadata view.  I want to automate the Section column value based off of the parent folder name of the file.

I understand that this can be done in [this way](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/171300/how-to-auto-fill-a-column-of-file-folder-based-on-parent-folders-value-of-that).  But I want it to be dynamic and adjust to when new Folders and files are created to automatically change the "Section" column.

[image: Example Setup]

Currently the Section column is not tied to any lists, I created the column in the settings like this:

[image: Section Column Settings]

I am open to using Flows, but when digging I cannot seem to find the value for that type of column, only columns in lists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flow with a trigger "When a file is created or modified" Then take the link to item. then you could split this url and get the folder of the file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Do you know what I would look for in Flow to change the column value?  I think that is where I am getting stuck

Comment: No matter what I do I cannot seem to find a section that contains the data in regular columns, only columns in lists.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Document Set and a SharePoint Designer workflow to achieve it.

The steps for you:
1. Create a column called "Column1" and set it as a shared Column in Document Set
2. Create a workflow and design it like the below:
[image]

3. For Start Options, set it like:
   [image]